# How to load a css file in generated index.html file?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Created a vue project using `vue create .` command. I am generating my own index.html file using the following configs:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'index.html',
    inject: true,    
}),
```

Now in index.html how I can link a css file? I tried like this but its not working

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~@/assets/custom/styles.css">
```

How to load the correct path in href?

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup entry javascript file like that

```
config.entry = {
 mainJs: 'main.js'
}
```

and import your root css file to that js.

```
import '../css/main.scss';
```

webpack will recognize that css and will inject into resulting html. you need to configure css loader in config.rules as well

```
    config.module = {
        rules: [
...
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                DEV ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
            ],
        }
        ]
```

say him 'inject: body'

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: 'body'
```

that will lead to js being injected into body, and css will remain in head

Comment: it injects into head tag but after the app.js file is initialized. I want to link in index.html directly so that until the vue.js is not kicked in I can show my custom css rules.

Comment: hm, try to say him 'inject: body', like as above

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my problem. I want to load a css file as soon as the index.html is loaded. If I use the above approach main.scss file is hooked into index.html by the main.js

Comment: But javascript does not 'hook' any css into index.html, when  you import css/scss into js it is just a hint for a webpack, that here is your styles to make css bundle from. If you try the approach above, you will get index.html with styles inside <head> and with js inside <body>. So you can have layout with your styles before js gets loaded. Is that what you want?

Comment: Run the app with above configuration and set an alert in main.js file. You will see first alert is appearing after that style is injected. I want the opposite.